# CMake - Link against exe on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, build, cmake, linker

I'm trying to make a plugin system for my application, and thus each plugin will need to link with my main application. This is fine on Linux and macOS, as I can just set the ENABLE_EXPORTS property of my executable target (`set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES ENABLE_EXPORTS 1`), and plugins will link just fine. On Windows however, `clang++` yells at me that it can't find `libws2editor.dll.a`.

```
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'ws2editor/libws2editor.dll.a'
```

Upon looking over the CMake docs, it says "For DLL platforms an import library will be created for the exported symbols and then used for linking." - This import library file (presumably the .dll.a) never seems to be created though.

So how can I get the CMake build on Windows to create this file, or otherwise link with an executable?

Comment: What do you mean by linking your plug-ins with your main application? As I know, to have a plug-in for your application, you should declare some interface in your application (your main executable) and implement it in your plug-in.

Comment: Do you set the ENABLE_EXPORTS property on your main executable?

Comment: @wxShayan Yes I do set ENABLE_EXPORTS on the main exe. Also I mean exactly what I said when I say "link against exe", my plugin has `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ws2editor)`

Comment: After a bit more digging around I came across https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/Plugin/CMakeLists.txt - When I clone the CMake repo and try and compile that test myself, it also fails with the same error when using clang + ninja! When building with MSVC/msbuild however it compiles just fine (My project fails to configure when generating files for MSVC however, and ideally I'd like to use the same build config across Win/Mac/Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can use `ar` to generate the .a file for me, regardless of generator - plugins seem to link and load just fine when doing this. Awesome! :)

```cmake
if(WIN32)
    #Invoke ar to generate a .dll.a from the .obj files, required to link plugins
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PRE_LINK
        COMMAND sh -c "${CMAKE_AR} cr lib${PROJECT_NAME}.dll.a $$(find . -name '*.obj' -printf '%p ')"
        COMMENT "Generating lib${PROJECT_NAME}.dll.a for external linking"
        )

    #Also add the install command for libws2editor.dll.a
    install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.dll.a DESTINATION bin)
endif(WIN32)
```